# How to save a xls file to my directory and Error message when opening the document PHP

Tags: php, excel

Hi guys I have two quires here, i'm currently working on getting making my php to create an excel document which works but when I open it I get an error message that says

> The file format and extension of 'Senior Managers Site Report.xls don't match. The file could be corrupt or unsafe. Unless you trust its sources, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?

I have no idea why it's saying this.

My second question is when I run my php at the moment it downloads my xls file but I want it so that it is saved to my website directory. How can I adjust this to get it to do this?

```
<?php

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/BI_spo.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $spo = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/BI_cont.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $cont = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/BI_site.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $site = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/BI_job.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $job = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/Ob_des.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $des1 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/Ob_act.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $act1 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/Ob_date.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $date1 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/GP_des.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $des2 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/GP_act.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $act2 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/GP_date.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $date2 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);    

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/FGR_des.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $des3 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/FGR_act.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $act3 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/FGR_date.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $date3 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);    

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/GIP1_Radio1.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $P1Radio1 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/GIP1_Radio2.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $P1Radio2 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);    

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/GIP1_Radio3.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $P1Radio3 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/GIP1_Radio4.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $P1Radio4 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/GIP1_Radio5.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $P1Radio5 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/GIP2_Radio1.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $P2Radio1 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/GIP2_Radio2.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $P2Radio2 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);    

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/GIP2_Radio3.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $P2Radio3 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/GIP2_Radio4.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $P2Radio4 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/GIP2_Radio5.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $P2Radio5 = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/GIP3_add.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $add = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);    

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/CB_name.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $name = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);    

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/CB_title.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $title = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);    

    $myFile=fopen("DATA/CB_date.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
    $date = fgets($myFile);
    fclose($myFile);

    Include_once 'PHPExcel.php';

    $sheet = new PHPExcel();

    $activeSheet = $sheet->getActiveSheet();

    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A1','Senior Managers Site Tour');

    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A3','BASIC INFORMATION');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A4','Site / Project / Object');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B4',$spo);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A5','Contract Number:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B5',$cont);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A6','Site Manager:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B6',$site);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A7','Job / Task Description:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B7',$job);

    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A9','OBSERVATION');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A10','Breif Description:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B10',$des1);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A11','Agreed Action:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B11',$act1);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A12','Close Date:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B12',$date1);

    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A14','GOOD PRACTICE');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A15','Breif Description:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B15',$des2);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A16','Agreed Action:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B16',$act2);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A17','Close Date:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B17',$date2);

    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A19','FEEDBACK GIVEN / RECEIVED');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A20','Breif Description:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B20',$des3);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A21','Agreed Action:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B21',$act3);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A22','Close Date:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B22',$date3);

    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A24','GENERAL IMPRESSION (CULTURE)');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A25','Is the CDP obvious - You Said / We Did Boards; Feedback Stations; Posters?:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B25',$P1Radio1);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A26','Are there any Speak Up Coaches on this site?');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B26',$P1Radio2);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A27','Are Focus Leader meetings happening?:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B27',$P1Radio3);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A28','Mention the Mental Tools, do people understand them?:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B28',$P1Radio4);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A29','Ask what "Never Harm" means to the teams:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B29',$P1Radio5);

    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A31','GENERAL IMPRESSION (SYSTEM)');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A32','Are first impressions good, site signage, induction etc?:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B32',$P2Radio1);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A33','Is the site tidy, well laid out etc?:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B33',$P2Radio2);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A34','Are morning briefings / daily risk assessment carried out?:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B34',$P2Radio3);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A35','Have all the team been briefed & signed onto the RAMS?:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B35',$P2Radio4);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A36','Ask what they would do if there was a change in the work activity i.e. not in RAMS?:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B36',$P2Radio5);

    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A38','GENERAL IMPRESSION (COMMENTS)');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A39','Additional Comments:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B39',$add);

    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A41','COMPLETED BY');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A42','Name:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B42',$name);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A43','Title:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B43',$title);
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('A44','Date:');
    $activeSheet->setCellValue('B44',$date);

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Senior Managers Site Tour.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($sheet, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');

    exit;

?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using PHPExcel to export to xlsx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895266/using-phpexcel-to-export-to-xlsx)

Comment: This Post has fixed my error message with excel I just don't understand how to make it save to the server rather than downloading when ran.

Comment: Instead of using `$objWriter->save('php://output');` you'd just replace php://output with a path on your server, such as `$objWriter->save('Senior Managers Site Tour.xls')`. In this case, you won't need any of the header lines at all, because you're not sending the spreadsheet to the browser.