# getUnderline of excel cellcontent using phpspreadsheet

Tags: phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I have use the code below to find if cell content has been underlined or not using phpexcel

```
$inputFileType  =PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($file);
$objReader      =PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel    =$objReader->load($file);
$checkUnderline =$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($col.$row)->getFont()->getUnderline();
```

The answer will be either 'single' or 'none'.
Now, I would like to know how to do this using PHPSpreadsheet.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works. This link has helped me.
([Read Xlsx file in PhpSpreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53823233/read-xlsx-file-in-phpspreadsheet))

```
    $inputFileType  =\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::identify($file);
    $objReader      =\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objPHPSpreadsheet           =$objReader->load($file);      
    $cellcontent_underlinestatus =$objPHPSpreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($col.$row)->getFont()->getUnderline();
```